# Algorithm: Factor Combinations

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion

I'm working on the following algorithm from Leetcode:

```
Numbers can be regarded as product of its factors. For example,

8 = 2 x 2 x 2;
  = 2 x 4.
Write a function that takes an integer n and return all possible combinations of its factors.

Note: 
You may assume that n is always positive.
Factors should be greater than 1 and less than n.
Examples: 
input: 1
output: 
[]
input: 37
output: 
[]
input: 12
output:
[
  [2, 6],
  [2, 2, 3],
  [3, 4]
]
input: 32
output:
[
  [2, 16],
  [2, 2, 8],
  [2, 2, 2, 4],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 4, 4],
  [4, 8]
]
```

Here's the code that I have thus far:

```
def get_factors(n)
    factors = [] 
    (2...n).each do |candidate|
        if n % candidate == 0
            factors << [candidate, (n/candidate)]
            get_factors(n/candidate).each do |factor_set|
                factors << [candidate] + factor_set
            end 
        end 
    end 
  factors
end
```

This code works really well, but doesn't handle duplicates (e.g [3, 2, 2] will be inserted along with [2, 2, 3]). I tried using a Set with the following code,

```
def get_factors(n)
    seen = Set.new
    factors = [] 
    (2...n).each do |candidate|
        if n % candidate == 0 && !seen.include?(candidate)
            factors << [candidate, (n/candidate)]
            get_factors(n/candidate).each do |factor_set|
                factors << [candidate] + factor_set
            end 
        end 
        seen << (n/candidate)
    end 
   factors 
end
```

but that only works to solve some test cases and not others. I'm not sure how to go about ensuring no duplicates in an efficient way? The really inefficient way is to generate some sort of hash value for each array depending on it's elements (and not dependent on order), and while this would work, there definitely should be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that if `m` is a factor of `n`, so is `n/m`. Moreover the largest factor `m` that is no larger than `n/m` satisfies `m*m <= n`. Therefore, you need only consider factors `m` up to `sqrt(n).floor`, and for each one found, add `m` and `n/m` to your list.

Answer (score 0):

I think always going forward is a good policy (i.e when checking, say, with 5, do not check with 2, 3, 4 etc). That way, searching for duplicates can be eliminated.

Comment: hey @mac -- well I'm recursively searching a smaller n, so it's n/2, n/3, n/4... do you mind explaining further what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since the algorithm already uses a lot of time, I don't see a problem sorting each answer and removing duplicates. This requires no proof to ensure it works, which the answer provided by mac does.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
require 'prime'

def get_factors(n)
  primes, nbr = Prime.prime_division(n).transpose
  powers = nbr.map { |m| (0..m).to_a }
  powers.shift.
         product(*powers).
         map { |pows| primes.zip(pows).reduce(1) { |t,(pr,po)| t * (pr**po) } }.
         sort
end
```

The array returned includes `1` and  `n` (which are factors of `n`). If those values should be excluded, replace `.sort` with `.sort - [1, n]`.

**Examples**

```
get_factors(24)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24]
get_factors(64)
  #=> [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
get_factors(90)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 30, 45, 90]
```

**Explanation**

Consider

```
n = 60
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = Prime.prime_division(30)
  #=> [[2, 2], [3, 1], [5, 1]]
```

Ergo, the primes of `30` are `2`, `3` and `5`, and

```
60 = 2**2 * 3**1 * 5**1
```

See [Prime::prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division). Continuing,

```
primes, nbr = a.transpose
  #=> [[2, 3, 5], [2, 1, 1]]
primes
  #=> [2, 3, 5]
nbr
  #=> [2, 1, 1]
powers = nbr.map { |m| (0..m).to_a }
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

This means that each factor will be the product of `0`, `1` or `2` `2`'s, `0` or `1` `3`'s and `0` or `1` `5`'s.

```
b = powers.shift
  #=> [0, 1, 2]
powers
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
c = b.product(*powers)
  #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1],
  #    [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
d = c.map { |pows| primes.zip(pows).reduce(1) { |t,(pr,po)| t * (pr**po) } }
  #=> [1, 5, 3, 15, 2, 10, 6, 30, 4, 20, 12, 60]
d.sort
  #=> [1, 5, 3, 15, 2, 10, 6, 30, 4, 20, 12, 60]
```

Consider now the calculation of `d`. The 10th element of `c` that is passed to the block is `[2, 0, 1]`. The block calculation for that element is as follows.

```
pows = [2, 0, 1]
e = primes.zip(pows)
  #=> [[2, 2], [3, 0], [5, 1]]
e.reduce(1) { |t,(pr,po)| t * (pr**po) }
  #=> 20
```

The `reduce` calculation is equivalent to

```
2**2 * 3**0 * 5**1
  #=> 4 * 1 * 5 => 20
```

The calculations for the other values of `c` passed to the block are similar.

Comment: Thanks @Cary. I'm unable to review at the moment but will do so when I can

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to replace the last line of your method with

```
factors.map(&:sort).uniq
```

which sorts all the subarrays and then eliminates duplicates.